# mysqli works when run directly but not when via js-ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have a php script that places information in a db.
When i run the script manually on the server all works as expected.
But when I run that very script via javascript using ajax the php script fails at the following line:

```
$connection=new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
```

And the error i get is
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/..

Which doesn't make any sense for I just ran that very script directly on the server with no problem.

I'm finding this error in /var/log/apache2/error.log.

Here's how my ajax call looks:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'db/insert.php',
    complete: function(response){
        //$('#output').html(response.responseText);
        alert('complete: '+response.responseText);
        },
    error: function(){
        //$('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
        alert('error');
        },
    async:"false",
    type:"POST",
    data:{visit_report:'1'}
    });
```

Why is the script failing in this way?

This question is continued here:
[Enable mysqli in my in-webserver copy of php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31535173/enable-mysqli-in-my-in-webserver-copy-of-php)

Comment: did you check if mysqli is enabled in your in-webserver copy of PHP? command line and SAPI have different .ini files, which don't necessarily have the same modules enabled.

Comment: Post the page you are calling with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Find you `php.ini` file, be careful there may be 2 of them. You probably want the one in your apache/bin folder.

Look for

```
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

Make sure it does not have an `#` comment character at the front of it.

If you are not sure where it lives try a `whereis php.ini`

Comment: wheres the apache/bin folder?

Comment: Sorry I dont know I am a windows user primarily. Did you try a `whereis`

Comment: i did whereis php.ini and it gives me a list of files that seems to be php executables.

Comment: Try this command to find it `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini`

Comment: that command gives me loaded configuration file as '/etc/php5/cli/php.ini'. I checked that file and I cant find the 'extension=php..' line there.

Comment: Read this http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/managing-php-5-4-extensions-on-ubuntu you need to run a `php5enmod mysqli`

Comment: i get message 'rm: remove write-protected regular empty file ‘/var/lib/php5/modules/cli/enabled_by_maint/mysqli’? i try to go to that folder but its protected as root. I don't know if its safe to do this. do you?

Comment: This is the standard mechanism for including a PHP extension on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue sometimes.

The issue is that when you call the page via ajax, all the server side includes and requires are dead. You have to explicitly call your db connection and make sure to include all your pages on the page you are calling via ajax so that they get created on that call.

Comment: I can't. Wherever you are creating your database connection, you need to create it again on any page you want to call with ajax. And make sure to include your needed includes on those pages too.