# Enable mysqli in my in-webserver copy of php

Tags: php, mysqli, webserver

As is discussed here:
[mysqli works when run directly but not when via js-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31523601/mysqli-works-when-run-directly-but-not-when-via-js-ajax)

I may need to enable mysqli in my webserver php copy.
It is enabled in the command line already.

How do I figure out if mysqli is enabled in a specific php copy,
and if it's not, how do I install it?

My webserver is running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS.

I have now tried having the following extensions in my php.ini file:

```
extension=mysqli.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

I have tried running them all separately, restarted mysql and apache, ran `sudo php5enmod mysqli` and then I run the page again, but the same error keeps popping up in /var/log/apache/error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/..
```

And nothing gets added to the sql table unless I run the insert.php from the server side.

When I have all three extension in the php.ini file I get the following errors are well:

```
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.lin:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.lin: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendOptimizer.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendOptimizer.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so:  /usr/lib64/php/modules/opcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is a *webserver php copy*?

Comment: I presume its a copy of the php language that gets implemented when php is called from a server.

Comment: :) check php.ini .. .with phpinfo() you can see which php.ini file is used for cli and *webserver php copy*

Comment: see /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini and try to include it or enable it and then restart apache

Comment: as you see. mysqli or pdo is not enabled ... so check your php.ini for enable mysqli ... i thought you forget to uncomment loading  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini in your current php.ini

Comment: i checked /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and there is nothing about enabling mysqli there. cant find that file in there at all.

Comment: add the relevant content of * /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini* to your php.ini

Comment: i checked it and it said just had the line 'extension=mysqli.so' so i added that line to /etc/php5/cli/php.ini, restarted apache and mysql but i still cant connect.

Comment: your *web* php ini file is **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini** you added it into **/etc/php5/cli/php.ini** which is not uesed!

Comment: yeah i added it to that one as well but to no avail.

Comment: then it seems you have 2 versions of php installed does php -v and phpinfo() gives the same version? if so try to **sudo apt-get install php5-mysql** and restart again ... notice the mysql provides both mysql as mysqli

Comment: yes, both php -v and phpinfo() give the same version. version 5.5.9. i ran that command but the error persists.

Comment: /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini has one uncommented line. 'extension=mysqli.so'.  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini has one uncommented line 'extension=pdo_mysql.so'. should i put either of those two lines in  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini? I have tried both, restarted apache and tried to insert into the mysql db via ajax and there is an error either way. ):

Comment: Can you show somewhere your `phpinfo()`?

Comment: http://89.160.129.62/apps/visiride/db/insert.php

Comment: Are you getting different errors each time, or always the same? What happens when you run the script in the browser by navigating to it as opposed to the ajax query? It definitely seems like this is just a configuration issue. You need to put extension=mysqli.so somewhere in your /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and then restart apache2. You should be able to confirm that the script does not execute correctly from the browser. If it does then there is some issue with the javascript.

Comment: Please specify the server os and  phpinfo() , also please include your code or the error you got

Comment: @doliver, i run the index file from the browser, which executes the ajax call. so im both navigating to it and running the ajax query. i put extension=mysqli.so in the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restart apache but i still get the 'class mysqli not found' error. i actually have three version of 'extension=x' that im guessing between. the link in my post contains one claim of another extension=x.

Comment: @tony i updated the question to include the server os. the php info is available four comments above this one, i added it to the question now and the error is provided in the link in the question.

Comment: This sounds trivial but did you try sudo service mysql restart ? It appears it is not installed in this version of php configuration it has nothing to do with ajax

Comment: yeah i did 'sudo service mysql restart'

Comment: @doliver i updated my answer to include some more error messages.

Comment: Whats the output of `grep extension /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` ?

Comment: extension_dir = "/usr/lib64/php/modules" extension=mysqli.so zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin.so zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ixed.lin zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendOptimizer.so

Comment: and quite a few more lines that are commented out.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson how do you run php from the server? Through a browser or the command line? If it's through the browser, then your ajax call MUST also work, if it's not, then you're not hitting the same page/server. Check your network inspector to see which absolute URL your ajax call is hitting

Comment: I run it through the terminal, i get status code 'ok' in the network inspector and it shows the correct domain file.

Comment: Does the file `/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so` exist?

Comment: there is no lib64 under /usr . but there is a lib, under it. '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so' does exist.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working for you! Posted an answer on changing extension_dir to match your system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments it appears your `extension_dir` was set to `/usr/lib64/php/modules` but this folder did not exist on your system.

On your system the mysqli.so module was actually found in `/usr/lib/php5/20121212/mysqli.so`

To resolve the issue, you can set the `extension_dir` to `/usr/lib/php5/20121212` so that the `extension=mysqli.so` line is able to find the shared object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile your PHP and add the code --enable-all to the end. (I think that command is right. If not the concept is) Your shared objects are not installed.

Comment: and how do i recompile the php?

Comment: How did you compile it in the first place?

Basically deleted it and recompile it.

Comment: i never  compiled it in the first place, it was just there upon install.

Answer (score 0):

You need open mysqli service from apache server and then restart apache server

Comment: how do i open the mysqli service from the apache server?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04.

Skip first step wich is about apache web srver.
Note that configuration for php cli (command line interface) is in a different file from the configuration for the php that your webserver uses.
If you need to configure php for apache, the default path is `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` on UBUNTU 14.02.

If you continue to experience issues with ioncude follow this link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ioncube-loader